# Apparently allocating memory and freeing it properly but program still crashes

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

So I've got a weird problem and can't seem to solve it. I have an ADT called TEAM:

```
typedef struct Team {
    char *name;
    int points;
    int matches_won;
    int goal_difference;
    int goals_for;
}TEAM;
```

I created a function to initialize variables of the TEAM* type with a given name:

```
TEAM *createTEAM (char *name){
    int error_code;

    if (name != NULL){
        if(strcmp(name, "") != 0){
            TEAM *new_team = (TEAM*)malloc(sizeof(TEAM));
            new_team->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(name));

            strcpy(new_team->name, name);
            new_team->points = 0;
            new_team->matches_won = 0;
            new_team->goal_difference = 0;
            new_team->goals_for = 0;

            return new_team;
        }else{
            error_code = EMPTY_STRING_CODE;
        }
    } else {

        error_code = NULL_STRING_CODE;
    }

    printf("Erro ao criar time.\n");
    printError(error_code);
    return NULL;
}
```

I also created a function to delete one of these TEAM* variables properly:

```
void deleteTEAM (TEAM *team_to_remove){
    free(team_to_remove->name);
    team_to_remove->name = NULL;
    free(team_to_remove);
    team_to_remove = NULL;
}
```

But when one or multiple test functions that I created (example below) run, the program sometimes crashes, sometimes doesn't. I've noticed that changing the names I use affects whether it crashes or not, even if they don't affect the test results.

```
int create_team_01(){
    int test_result;
    TEAM *Teste = createTEAM("Cruzeiro");

    if (strcmp(Teste->name, "Cruzeiro") == 0){
        test_result = TRUE;
    }else test_result = FALSE;

    _assert(test_result); //just a macro function that will check the argument and return 1 if it's false

    deleteTEAM(Teste);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't see any problems with memory allocation or freeing. Still, the debugger complains a lot about the first free() (can't find bounds) of the deleteTEAM function. Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

P.S.: I've even tried checking the mallocs' results, but it doesn't seem to be the problem either, so I removed it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: omg, thanks dude... I see how dumb I'm now, I've been the whole day trying to fix this.

Comment: Generally, code is easier to understand if you test something and then do something, rather than test something else.  Think about the merits of `if (name == NULL) error_code = NULL_STRING_CODE; else if (name[0] == '\0') error_code = EMPTY_STRING_CODE; else { … }`.  It has the additional merit of keeping the indentation level smaller.

Comment: @Stuart thanks for the advice! I guess you're right.